# Strapi development using a remote server

Tags: remote-server, strapi

I'm pretty new to strapi.

I'm trying to run a project in development mode on a remote server.

I have tried changing the configuration in the /config/environments/development/server.json, however when I start up I still get

```
One more thing...
Create your first administrator � by going to the administration panel at:
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ http://localhost:1337/admin │
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

I've checked the documentation and done a number of searches, but I haven't found a solution where I can easily set the host to 0.0.0.0 or define the hostname.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello! I don't understand, what is the problem you have?

Comment: The problem I was having was that while the settings were pointed to localhost, I was unable to access the rendered pages. I do almost all of my development on remote servers, and localhost usually does not work when accessing the remote server.  My understanding at this point is that strapi will use localhost by default.  This can be updated, and goes into effect after a rebuild.  If there isn't sufficient RAM, the build won't complete.  Based on other tests, the location that the instructions direct you to, don't seem to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The virtual machine I was using was too small.  The guidelines are included at https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/installation/digitalocean-one-click.html#step-2-create-a-project, but not in the general tutorial.